# How to create a sqlite recursive view that properly uses an index for the first row

Tags: sqlite, view, query-optimization

We're using sqlite version 3.16.0.

I would like to create some views to simplify some common recursive operations I do on our schema.  However, these views turn out to be significantly slower than running the SQL directly.

Specifically, a view to show me the ancestors for a given node:

```
CREATE VIEW ancestors AS
        WITH RECURSIVE ancestors
             (
                   leafid
                 , parentid
                 , name
                 , depth
             )
             AS
             (SELECT id
                   , parentid
                   , name
                   , 1
                FROM objects
               UNION ALL
              SELECT a.leafid
                   , f.parentid
                   , f.name
                   , a.depth + 1
                FROM objects f
                JOIN ancestors         a
                  ON f.id = a.parentid
        ) ;
```

when used with this query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ancestors
 WHERE leafid = 157609;
```

yields this result:

```
sele  order          from  deta
----  -------------  ----  ----
2     0              0     SCAN TABLE objects
3     0              1     SCAN TABLE ancestors AS a
3     1              0     SEARCH TABLE objects AS f USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
1     0              0     COMPOUND SUBQUERIES 0 AND 0 (UNION ALL)
0     0              0     SCAN SUBQUERY 1

Run Time: real 0.374 user 0.372461 sys 0.001483
```

Yet running the query directly (with a WHERE constraint on the initial query for the same row), yields:

```
        WITH RECURSIVE ancestors
             (
                   leafid, parentid, name, depth
             )
             AS
             (SELECT id, parentid , name,  1
                FROM objects
               WHERE id = 157609
             UNION ALL
             SELECT a.leafid, f.parentid , f.name, a.depth + 1
               FROM objects f
               JOIN ancestors         a
                 ON f.id = a.parentid
             )
       SELECT *
         FROM ancestors;

Run Time: real 0.021 user 0.000249 sys 0.000111

sele  order          from  deta
----  -------------  ----  ----
2     0              0     SEARCH TABLE objects USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
3     0              1     SCAN TABLE ancestors AS a
3     1              0     SEARCH TABLE objects AS f USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
1     0              0     COMPOUND SUBQUERIES 0 AND 0 (UNION ALL)
0     0              0     SCAN SUBQUERY 1
```

The second result is around 15 times faster because we're using the PK index on objects to get the initial row, whereas the view seems to scan the entire table, filtering on leaf node only after the ancestors for all rows are found.

Is there any way to write the view such that I can apply a constraint on a consuming select that would be applied to the optimization of the initial query?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for the `WHERE leafid = 157609` to be moved inside the first subquery. This is the [push-down optimization](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#the_push_down_optimization), and SQLite tries to do it whenever possible.

However, this is possible only if the database is able to prove that the result is guaranteed to be the same. For this particular query, you know that the transformation would be valid, but, at the moment, there is no algorithm to make this proof for recursive CTEs.

Comment: That's unfortunate, although it feels like there could be some limited form of proof that could work with certain well-constrained forms of CTE that would at least allow some subset of recursive views to use this feature.

Without it, it makes me question the utility of creating a recursive view in the first place, for anything other than trivial and/or small tables.  Having to pay for an N-squared operation on a large table every time you want to examine a small subset seems not worth the abstraction you gain from the view.